# Factory Object and return null on object creation failure

Tags: php, null, factory-pattern

I have created a factory class that creates a Laravel application instance and it works well. I am just not so sure about some of the decision I have made around what my factory method should return in case the application cannot be created.

```
class LaravelApplicationFactory{
  public static function createApplication($options = array()){
     if(isset($options['app.dir']){
        return new Application($options['app.dir']);
     }else{
       return null;
     }
   }
 }
```

I am asking this question because I know that at some point I read that rather than returning null values one should instead throw exceptions.

If this is the case how best can I leverage the factory pattern without embroidering my implementation with flawed design decisions?

Client code would consume my factory as follows for the time being:

```
//file: index.php

/** imports */
use cAspire\Core\Factory\LaravelApplicationFactory;

LaravelApplicationFactory::createApplication([
  'app.dir' => __DIR__
]);
```

This is inspired by the bootstrap file which can be found in any Laravel 5.* implementation under the [bootstrap.php](https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel5-3-example/blob/master/bootstrap/app.php) file.

Comment: what is the code that uses the result of the factory? who is the client of factory?

Comment: The client would most likely be an index file for now that uses the factory to pass in any required configurations in order for the application instance to be created. With that being said I do not think and feel like even in any context we should be returning `null` values as it may promote uncertainty to client code leading to unnecessary null checks. Throwing an exception sounds the best option but again I am not quite sure. See my edit for the input to this wrapper class.

Comment: I'd throw an exception so I recognised the issue, otherwise you're just going to get an obscure exception due to the object being null and have headache trying to understand whats going wrong.

Comment: @Jonno Thanks. I figured that should be the best way to go about but was just not so sure about it.

Comment: just 2 cents. Assuming that  `index.php` is the entry point, and object being returned from `LaravelApplicationFactory` is the very top object that has very top responsibilities to handle requests, and there is no other code that would handle exceptional situations (and inability to create an application is obviously the one) a question arises: "what the response should be and where would it come from?"

Comment: @xmike This is still a work in progress. The idea is to wrap what Laravel Framework makes available as an application instance through the app directory into a customized implementation to afford myself an opportunity to architecture my applications according to the architecture I will define myself and not being dictated by the framework I am using. Eventually I want to be able to port my application from one framework to another without worrying about the coupling that takes place if you rely on frameworks to build business solutions. I will update this question with an answer when done.